# show notification message to browser

Tags: google-chrome, notifications

I notice that all modern browsers, Chrome, Safari, Firefox has a Notification API.

But I can NOT find out doc/example about how to use this API to send notification from web site. like sending a notification from my site to Google Now?

Answer (score 1):

I finally found out that There is a more standardized API object Notification, [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/notification) is some doc about the usage